# Python XML Parsing using loop

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing

I have a XML file which looks like the one below:

```
<A><B><C>
    <D>
        .
        .
        .
    </D>
    <E>
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
    </D>
    <F>
        <F1>
            <F11>
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
            </F11>
        </F1>
        <F1>
            <F11>
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
            </F11>
        </F1>
    </F>
```

I want to parse the tag named **F11** which can be present n number of times. This is a sub-tag of **F1** and F1 can also be present for n times. I'm stuck in parsing, though I can find out how many times `F1` appears in the xml file. Below is the code:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('final_resp.xml','r') as f:
        doc = (f.read())

    dom = parseString(doc)
    f1_count = len(dom.getElementsByTagName('F1'))
    for x in range(0,f1_count):
        //parsing of each F1 tag
```

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out the solution that works. Using `xml.etree.ElementTree` we can find the occurrences of required tag and parse it.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for responses in root.findall('./B/C/F/F1'):
    date = responses.find('./F11/DATE-REPORTED').text
    print(a)
```

Answer (score -1):

First you need to have a valid XML file like :

data.xml:

```
<note>
<A>Tove</A>
<B>Jani</B>
<C>Reminder</C>
<D>Don't forget me this weekend!</D>
<E>SOme data</E>
<F>
  <F1>
    <F11>
      Some F11 Datas
    </F11>
  </F1>
  <F2>
    <F12>
      Some F12 data
    </F12>
  </F2>
</F>
</note>
```

You can use pythons inbuilt xml module to get data:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for item in root[5]:
    print(item[0].text)
```

XML is a data carrier format, you cannot use duplicate tags

Comment: XML Documents Must Have a Root Element.
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp
Get your basics cleared first.

Comment: Thanks for the reference link. I will definitely go through it, but for now at-least I have a working solution. And, yes, in case you did not notice, root element is "A"